# Where can i find a precompiled verson of the Mesa 3D Library?

Tags: 13.04, graphics, package-management, mesa

I'm pretty new to the Ubuntu community and I was wondering what where I could find precompiled versions of the Mesa's librarys.

I keep following instructions and I keep trouble shooting but i can never seem to compile it, regardless of what I do.

So that why i was wondering, is there a place or a person who could give me the precompiled version of the Mesa 3D Librarys? Preferably 9.5+ because DotA 2 looks like an array of health bars and shadows without it.

Thanks in advance, David.

Answer (score 0):

[How to update OpenGL Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)