# How to update OpenGL Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, steam, opengl

I recently upgraded to 14.04, then I installed steam, and TF2. I get this error message:

> Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.

[image: "Could not find required OpenGL entry point "glGetError"! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.]

Anyway, I know I need to update my OpenGL Driver, my question is how do I do it?

**EDIT: I installed `mesa` and entered `glxinfo | grep version` into Terminal and got this,**

[image]

[image]
**New Edit: After looking into the first answer, I did all of the steps, and restarted my computer, when I launched steam on startup, I got the following error,**

Comment: First you need to determine if you are using openGl.  Open a terminal window, and enter `glxinfo | grep version`  If this produces errors, you will need to `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` and re-run the command.  Please post the results into your question.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I did what you said, and it is now in my question!

Comment: Thanks - future reference - you can copy the highlighted text (ctrl-shift-c) past it into the question, and then press ctrl-k while it's highlighted in the question to format the text as code...

Comment: Do you know your graphics card?  It seems like you are running the 32-bit version of Ubuntu

Comment: @CharlesGreen Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2, and yes it is 32-bit. This desktop is fairly old

Comment: K - some people may not like my answer, but I'll post it below in a few seconds.  I note that you also have some non-upgraded packages - is that by design?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just updated yesterday so everything should be up-to date. @CharlesGreen

Comment: What video card do you have? Can you post the output of `glxinfo|grep render.*:`

Comment: How about installing latest drivers from amd and nvidia http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86

Comment: @Johnn Did you solve your problem? If not look at this it might help http://askubuntu.com/a/538907/215526

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/506349/opengl-glx-context-is-not-using-direct-rendering-which-may-cause-performance-pr check this out. It worked for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 “could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/539858/ubuntu-14-04-could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror)

Answer (score 9):

Be careful when using Charles Green's advice.

On the sudo apt-get upgrade step, you might see:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
    required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2     libdrm2:i386
  libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libva1 libwayland-egl1-mesa mesa-common-dev xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

The key part is that the upgrade I wanted to do didn't happen:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
```

You will have to:

```
sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back>
```

I ended up doing:

```
sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa
```

For more information on this problem see: ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it/185402#185402)

Comment: I need to undo this, I'm getting weird glitches :(

Comment: @MinaMichael : look at Charles Green's post. He has a section on how to remove it.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you have a version of OpenGl, just not one new enough to run the application that you are looking for.

To get a slightly newer version of the OpenGl drivers, I would recommend the oibaf drivers from the [launchpad website](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) - these implement OpenGl 3.0, and are pretty stable.

To install open a terminal window and enter

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To remove, you can use ppa-purge

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Comment: This didn't work, I'm getting a different error when I login to steam, i'll edit it into my post

Comment: If you install oibaf's ppa - you can't remove it with ppa-purge. Well, you can, but you will screw up your whole OS.

Comment: @Heihachi I've used `ppa-purge` a couple of times without issue - what happened on your system?

Comment: After doing this, on Kubuntu 14.04.2 it worked perfect. But, i made a new fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04.3, and did the same process above, but this time, the game drops on FPS, 20-30, 50 fps max. Also the videos on Dragon Player go slow sometimes , as the FPS drop on Dota2. I'm doing the purge right now, and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my fix / answer here for this exact same issue:

[Ubuntu 14.04 “could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'!"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539858/ubuntu-14-04-could-not-find-required-opengl-entry-point-glgeterror/592692#592692)

Have a read