# OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems. (steam) AMD DRIVER

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, steam, 14.10

When I start steam in a terminal, I get the following error messages

```
charlie@SteamMPL:~$ steam
rm: no se puede borrar «/home/charlie/.steam/steam»: Es un directorio
rm: no se puede borrar «/home/charlie/.steam/bin»: Es un directorio
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2014-08-03 11:50:13] Startup - updater built Jul 15 2014 18:14:26
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1405474565_client)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1405474565_client)
[2014-08-03 11:50:14] Checking for update on startup
[2014-08-03 11:50:14] Buscando actualizaciones disponibles...
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1405474565_client)
[2014-08-03 11:50:14] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1405474565, installed version 1405474565
[2014-08-03 11:50:14] Nothing to do
[2014-08-03 11:50:14] Verificando instalación...
[2014-08-03 11:50:14] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2014-08-03 11:50:15] Verification complete
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1405474565_client)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0803/115015:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.
```

Hardware information:

- CPU: AMD Athlon x4 760k
- GPU: AMD Radeon R7 250 1 GB GDDR5 (Driver: Catalyst 14.4)
- RAM: 8 GB DDR3 1600

What can I do to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Well, I guess no-one gets my bounty. I solved the problem by downgrading the proprietary NVidia driver from `340` to `304` (and possibly a combination of the below).

Answer (score 45):

Steam ships with it's own gcc libraries, which are outdated and do not work on distributions with newer libraries. For further information, check out: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/steam#Steam_runtime_issues

**To solve your problem on Ubuntu 14.04, close Steam and run:**

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

**On 14.10, the path changed, commands are similar:**

```
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

**or**

```
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/bin32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

Comment: Amazing answer, just one thing, instead of saying "libstdc++.so.6" say "libstdc++.so.*" because there can be a different version installed. To those who did the upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10, the steam path will stay the same for the runtime

Comment: Does anybody know if Steam will update their package to actually run on 14.10? It's a mess right now...

Comment: Seems like  this solution is working. GOD BLASE YOU MY SAVIOR!

Comment: It seems like removing files would be a bad solution, but this seems to work brilliantly :-p Kudos. Here's hoping Volvo fixes soon.

Comment: doesnt work, whabts going on. i still get the same error

Comment: first answer from of half of a dozen which actually worked for me (on 14.10) !

Comment: Third solution worked for me @Ubuntu 14.10 with R9 270

Comment: Didnt help me, using 14.05 and prop nvidia driver...

Comment: I changed the path for deletion under Ubuntu 14.10 to ~/.steam/bin then deleted the files that are listed originally in this thread. Tested and works fine.

Comment: Seriously awesome answer

Comment: @NickBailuc @aXept perhaps you need to do a `sudo ldconfig -v` after deleting the libs? Remember that `libstdc++6` is one of THE core libraries in the system (dozens of dozens of programs depend on it) and if the Steam installer *incorporates* its own versions to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (respectively `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf` or whatever) using `ldconfig`, the mess is there in no time. Running the command as I suggested will again cause the old libs to be __removed from the internal list__ for good.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work, same error still... Curiously this only started to happen recently.

Comment: \@aXept Doesn't work for me, either, with proprietary nvidia driver. FWIW, this problem developed right after switching from the default "generic" driver.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu16.04 (the third set of commands; `rm ~/.steam/bin32/ ...... ` etc)

Answer (score 6):

I did the following

```
$ tar cjvf ~/.steam/gcc_libs_backup.tar.bz2 $(find ~/.steam | grep -e libstdc++ -e libgcc_s) && rm $(find ~/.steam | grep -e libstdc++ -e libgcc_s)
```

and then everything worked. If it's necessary you'll have a backup of the libraries in `~/.steam/gcc_libs_backup.tar.bz2`

Comment: This is the most generic answer, FTW! But you might try `find ~/.steam -name 'libstdc++*' -o -name 'libgcc_s*'` instead of adding a `grep`.

Comment: It looks like everything relevant under `.steam` is a symlink to something under `.local/share/Steam`, so I ran this command on that folder instead. It did not work, though.

Answer (score 3):

That same error has occured to me and the problem was with the amd driver. Try doing the following:

uninstall steam
uninstall amd driver
install steam
start steam
setup everything
install amd driver

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for stating the most obvious solution to any software problem. Genius!

Comment: So clever, indeed

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.04(or 1 version before/after) there was a bug which gave the same error message when the amd driver was installed before steam, the way to fix it, install steam before amd driver, and then install the amd driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and couldn't resolve it, but thanks to @user22153 I was able to solve it, but with a little difference. (I created a new answer, so I could easier post the commands I used, also for future reference. :D) All creds got to @user22153.

```
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

So, simply put, if the above mentioned code (by @user22153) doesn't work, look around until you are able to find the files.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error after installing version 346.47 of the nvidia Geforce drivers on Ubuntu 14.04.2. During installation of the drivers, I got a message saying that the 32 bit compatibility libraries could not be installed, but I stupidly ignored it. Running back through the installer for the video drivers, and making sure to install those 32bit libraries fixed the issue.