# Ubuntu 14.10 upgrade and reinstall, Steam OpenGL problems?

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, steam, thinkpad, opengl

I'm having some serious issues after updating to Ubuntu 14.10. Back in 14.04, I got constant error messages, and after updating, they seemed to go away for the most part, but then the came roaring back... I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.10, and not much has improved. now get the following message whenever I open Steam.

"OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems.

For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9938-EYZB-7457."

I've gone to the Additional Drivers application, found on the Applications lens, and changed to all the available drivers, and none of them work. To be quite frank, the change from Windows 7 to Ubuntu has been nothing but bumps. But does that mean I haven't enjoyed it? I loved it! I love finding and fixing these problems, but I'm sad to admite, I do need help with this. So thank you in advance!

```
Computer:
Brand: Lenovo
Product: ThinkPad T510 
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 620 @ 2.67GHz × 4 
Video Card: Lenovo GeForce 3100M (Gallium on NVA8)
RAM: 5.7 GiB
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: What is the output of glxinfo (read the support article), and `lspci -v`? You can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/554839/edit) this into your question.

Comment: I'm sorry @Wilf that confused me. Could you reword that?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.

Found the solution over there:
[OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems. (steam) AMD DRIVER](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506349/opengl-glx-context-is-not-using-direct-rendering-which-may-cause-performance-pr/538907#538907)

Contrary to the solution thread's topic, it's not an AMD issue, but seems to involve all systems running the open-source Gallium3D drivers on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Can you please post some of the relevant parts of that answer here, in case the other question is closed or edited? That ensures your answer remains helpful.

Comment: The other question is never going to be closed, as the duplicate one is in fact the one you're reading.