# CS:GO mini stutters

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, games, steam

My pc:

- i7-4770k @3.5 GHz
- 16GB of RAM
- NVIDIA GTX 780
- Ubuntu Gnome 14.10

I get steady 290+ FPS on Windows when playing CS:GO

I've recently moved to Ubuntu since I don't have to use Adobe for work anymore and I really want to stay here.
I was trying to play Counter Strike: Global Offensive with friends and I encountered some obstacles. I managed to get rid of Steam OpenGL bug by deleting some Steam libraries as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/538907/389367).

When I used proprietary NVIDIA drivers (331.113) from "additional drivers" I experienced very low fps in CS, dropping below 60. With Nouveau display driver it was even worse. Yesterday I managed to install latest NVIDIA drivers (346.47) and now I have more than 200 fps when playing. But my happiness didn't last long.

**I experience mini stutters every few minutes.** The fps counter doesn't show any drops, game just freezes for time that feels like half a second. These stutters are acceptable when not in combat, but they did happen when dueling someone and caused me to lose.
I have no idea how to find the source of the problem and I hope you guys will be able to help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like I dealt with that problem. If anyone experiences this stutters, here is what I did:

**1. Turn off steam overlay and steam notifications in game.**

**2. Go to NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PowerMizer -> Set Preffered Mode to "Prefer Maximum Performance".**

After setting that I played 2 whole competitive games with no stutters.

Comment: I was having mini stutterings during common usage (development + background music). It was so annoying. Fortunately setting Maximum Performance + OpenGL Settings -> Sync to VBlank on a 980TI did it for me. Thanks for the help @safian!

Comment: it didn't help for me. Do you have any more idea?