# Can't get CS:GO to stop stuttering

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games, steam

I just recently installed ubuntu 16.04 onto my PC, I am also a pretty big gamer, I love Counter-Strike:Global Offensive, but for the life of me i cant get the game to run smoothly, In windows i get 200+ Fps silky smooth, but in ubuntu it randomly stutters/slows down, making the game very annoying to play. (this game is super competitive). I really want to say goodbye to windows, but i cant live without my CS GO!

I have installed the latest nvidia drivers and all OS updates have been downloaded and installed.

here are my specs:
Intel Core i5 4690k
16gb of ram
Nvidia Geforce GTX 980Ti

I can max any game in windows, the power of my PC shouldnt be a problem right? Thank you all for any help! I am eager to get rid of windows, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering if you have tried these settings here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/599068/csgo-mini-stutters?rq=1

Comment: After trying the suggestions in your link the game does seem to be running a lot smoother with a more consistent frame rate, however I am still getting random mini/micro stutters, not sure what is causing it. It's like the game will go slow motion every 15 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Kubuntu 16.10, but I fixed it today.

The update center showed up a notification after every boot, that third party software may be needed for my system to work properly. I clicked on the notification and a dialog opened. It took some time, but after a few minutes the dialog showed the message, that the system needs the package `intel-microcode:amd64` to run properly.

Here is the log entry of the operation apt did:

```
Start-Date: 2017-03-26  17:02:24
Install: intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20160714.1), iucode-tool:amd64 (1.6.1-1ubuntu0.1, automatic)
End-Date: 2017-03-26  17:02:36
```

Since I installed those two packages CS:GO runs perfectly smoothly with the graphics pushed to the maximum.