# steam cs:go, nvidia graphics - fps and game smoothness issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games, bumblebee

I have a desktop graphics card (NVIDIA GTX 1060, 6GB). I have nearly the latest Nvidia drivers installed (v 387.12). Cuda version is also the latest (9. something). OpenGL version is 4.6.0. I basically used [this](https://gist.github.com/whizzzkid/37c0d365f1c7aa555885d102ec61c048) guide for installation. I tested it upto the `sudo prime-select nvidia` and everything seems to be working fine. Running `glxgears` utilises nearly 60% of GPU, which makes me a bit concerned, as I feel this is capped somehow, I am not sure how, maybe its normal.

In Windows with maximum game settings (CS:GO) I used to get ~220 fps though not constant, but I could never feel a compromise in my game smoothness (it is most likely because of direct-x).

Coming back to the github gist which I referred for installation - I am a bit hesitant in installing `bumblebee` because it has not been updated in a while and I don't want to proceed before knowing the technicalities. **My first question** would be what are the technical advantage of using `bumblebee`, what would be the upper edge for letting bumblebee control my driver load rather than OS. Also I would like to know a bit more about `optirun` and `primusrun`, couldn't seem to get my head around this stuff.

Now coming to the current stage of installation, looks like everything is working perfectly fine. When I run the game (cs:go) gpu does show some load, temperature does rise, the only issue I face now is the fps and gameplay smoothness (its not the game ping, I have a ping of 20 ms). At the highest setting I manage to get around 170 fps (lesser than windows, which again seems like a problem). [UPDATE HERE: The fps has not improved by anything, it drops down to 60-70]. Maybe there are some more settings that need to be performed which might improve my frame rates further (I would like to know about them, even though it is not a thread for cs go settings). But now **my second question** which doesn't seems to get resolved- I just cannot get the game to be smooth. There are many articles on improving the game stutters - ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599068/csgo-mini-stutters)), ([here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/csgo-osx-linux/issues/141)), ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765689/cant-get-csgo-to-stop-stuttering)), ([here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/618458030671975050/)) but nothing seems to fix it. The game is simply  not smooth enough for an enjoyable experience. help me figure out all these problems.

Sorry for the long post and crappy English. I have a good experience with linux, so I would recommend being as technical as possible (might learn a lot of new things).

Here are my OpenGL settings in Nvidia control panel.

[image]

and these are my gfx information

[image]

PS: if anymore information about the drivers, kernel resources is required I would be more than happy to share. I have updated to kernel version 4.13.0 as suggested in the gist.

Thank you!