# When mic is on, windowed application frames stutter in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, desktop-environments

## 1 Explaining the problem

Playing some games caused frame stuttering once in a few seconds, which was really apparent when playing csgo in windowed mode, and could be avoided by playing in a fullscreen mode. Didn't cause any problems in audio.

I noticed that while I was in voice chat in discord, and my headset mic was off, the problem didn't occur, but when I turned it on from the switch again it came back.

### 1.1 NVIDIA X

I tried to fix stutters by changing checkbox checks in NVIDIA X screen OpenGL settings, I really dont recommend changing any display configurations there as it caused more problems on my double screen setup.

I reverted by reinstalling graphics driver using Software & Updates -> Additional drivers. I set the Image quality high as increasing performance caused screen flickering in CSGO.

### 1.2 Pavucontrol

Using pavucontrol I tried to change the configuration and reduce the volume so much that it wouldn't send static noise. It worked, but I couldn't hear my voice anymore with only 10% (-60 dB).

Then I tried to change built-in audio mode from duplex to output. Mic caused even larger stutter problems. In input mode there was no frame stutters, but I couldn't hear anything anymore as there was only input channel in use.

## 2 Solution I found for the problem

I solved the problem with some module changes in /etc/pulse/default.pa.

By commenting row **load-module module-suspend-on-idle**. Disabling caused constant static noise from mic.

And adding **load-module module-echo-cancel** near end of the file. Echo cancel module fixed the static noise away.

### 2.1 My PC parts

- Motherboard: MSI Z170A PC Mate
- CPU: i5-6600K
- GPU: GTX 1060 6GB
- Graphics driver: NVIDIA 396.54
- RAM: 16 GB

Motherboard has Realtek® ALC887 Codec. The headset is Steelseries Siberia v2, which hasn't caused any problems before in windows 7, 8.1 or 10.

### 2.2 Posts

Posts that helped me:

- [CS:GO mini stutters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599068/csgo-mini-stutters)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114602/pulseaudio-sink-always-suspended
- [Realtime noise-removal with PulseAudio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio)

Post that I checked, but didn't get to work:

- https://forum.level1techs.com/t/csgo-on-ubuntu-18-04-stutters-low-fps/130339

## Question

**Will there will be any further trouble in this solution?** I don't see a reason for that module-suspend-on-idle. Maybe it saves a lot battery if I were using a laptop?

Currently it seems to behave pretty much the same as before, but I have more control over how to adjust the static noise in the mic (I like it a lot).

Desktop seems slightly more stable, but it could be my imagination.

**Edit:** Mic has changed in multiple restarts... I can no longer cancel some volume and then boost the remaining... I have no idea why it is so...

**Edit2:**

I disabled echo-cancellation as it wasn't what I was looking for even though it worked for a while for some reason... well, it was for echo...

There's no equalizor for input audios, or additional boost control for mic in pulseaudio for further adjustment.

I added 10 dB boost to front mic in alsamixer, lowered boost in pavucontrols to around 45%... It reduced the static noise for now and mic sound is high enough for others to hear me.