# OpenGL Error Steam Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ati, radeon, opengl

It seems now, that after installing 14.10, and Steam shortly after the updates and drivers installed, I get a pop-up that explains an OpenGL rendering error that may cause performance issues. I have an HP Pavillion, AMD A8 CPU, Radeon R5 graphics, 12GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this thread if you did not already, it might help.

[OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems. (steam) AMD DRIVER](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506349/opengl-glx-context-is-not-using-direct-rendering-which-may-cause-performance-pr)