# How do I enable direct rendering for Steam games with ATI?

Tags: ati, games, steam

From glxinfo I know that my direct rendering is disabled. I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506349/opengl-glx-context-is-not-using-direct-rendering-which-may-cause-performance-pr) but answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the graphics drivers for your card.
Run this command to get your graphics card model.

```
lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'
```

Afterwards make sure to look up a decent guide to installing proper graphics drivers for your model of video card.

Here are a few good guides for AMD and NVIDIA cards.

NVIDIA: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia
AMD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Answer (score 0):

edit: If I use X-ORG default drivers I have enabled direct rendering but my PC is struggling to play games I used to play without any problems. and when I install fglrx ATI/AMD drivers it stays disabled