# running dota 2 , given a 'glGEtError'

Tags: graphics, opengl

I am trying to play Dota2
but my system is showing

I Searched ... and followed this link.

[How to update OpenGL Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

using 
`glxinfo | grep version`
shows following

```
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
idip@idip-System-Product-Name:~$ ^C
idip@idip-System-Product-Name:~$ ^C
idip@idip-System-Product-Name:~$
```

Later I run dota2

but getting same error

> Could not find OpenGl entry point 'glGEtError' either your video card
>   is unsupported or openGl driver needs to be updated .

Comment: Please indicate the release you're on - do you use 14.04 LTS or is that just what you linked?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using outdated distro, you can read the following on PPA page

> Supported Ubuntu versions: 
>   - 14.04 (trusty)
>   - 14.10 (utopic

Try using xorg-edgers PPA. First disable oibaf PPA
     `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
Then add xorg-edgers
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Done, all the steps ,,, getting the same eror