# Open Gl 3.0 to 3.3

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

I know theirs literally a hundred of these but none of them have helped me i am unable to play any 3D games because open gl is on version 3.o when i need 3.3 i have a Radeon HD 7950 i cannt use any of the command line stuff that have been mentioned and i have also tried to find these third party drivers that i cant find so far these are the guides i have tried.

https://superuser.com/questions/741348/upgrading-from-opengl-3-0-to-3-3-on-ubuntu-linux

[I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and there's no fglrx!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744050/im-using-ubuntu-16-04-and-theres-no-fglrx)

[How to update OpenGL Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

i have literally been pulling my hair out for a week please please someone end my suffering and help me

Answer (score 0):

I can not relate to the problem you are having but I found a comment on a similar post you could try:

https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/37kixd/ubuntu_radeon_hd_7900_driver/crnt76d

Hope this helps.