# Minecraft constantly crahsing, Java 8 OPENJDK

Tags: java, games, minecraft, openjdk

after I installed Minecraft, I installed Java, and then I launched my game on 1.10.2 and I even tryed 1.10

My crash log:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't do that.

Time: 7/28/16 7:10 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at bcx.ar(SourceFile:624)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:432)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:951)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    ... 4 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.ar(SourceFile:624)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:432)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 4.4.0-31-generic
    Java Version: 1.8.0_91, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 52439632 bytes (50 MB) / 152907776 bytes (145 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: Looks like an OpenGl exception. What driver are you using for your GPU?

Comment: I installed from here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0 
This version: Graphics Installer 1.4.0 for Ubuntu* 15.10, 64-bit
I have Intel Graphics 2xxx

Comment: @KillerDoge What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @edwinksl Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @KillerDoge Then why are you using that installer? The site even says "This release of the Graphics Installer is targeted at Ubuntu 15.10 or Fedora 23.  Ubuntu 16.04 is already current with the latest Q1 2016 Intel Graphics stack and therefore no Graphics Installer is needed."

Comment: @edwinksl  know, but it still crashes!

Comment: @KillerDoge - Try running MC in a clean-installed 16.04 VM.

Comment: @AndroidDev I just reinstalled Ubuntu an hour ago

Comment: I helped a friend install MC on a clean install of 16.04 with an i7-6700k, and it worked OOTB.

Comment: Then what are the priorities, what should I install first?

Comment: We installed, ran `sudo apt-get upgrade`, rebooted, ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, rebooted, ran `sudo apt-get update`, then ran `sudo apt-get install default-jre`, and then proceeded to download and run the Minecraft JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before! :D

You aren't running a good graphics driver or window manager. The same thing happens when you use `xiwi` on a Chromebook, which is a Chromebook window, not capable of handling GL requests.

Looking across Ubuntu forms, I found this:

> Steps:
>
> From a terminal
>
> 1) sudo apt-get update
>
> - This will update your apt database to the most recent available packages.
>
> 2) sudo apt-get install build-essential
>
> - This installs the necessary development tools for building source code.
>
> 3) sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
>
> - This is the GL/GLUT package.

(https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345177)

I suggest you try this, and see what happens.

If you can, install the official drivers for your GPU. (The top answer for [How to update OpenGL Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) might work for you.)