# Ubuntu 16.04 Dying Light openGL problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl, amd-graphics

I've been trying to get dying light running on my system as of late, and for the past few days i have seen nothing but failure. After multiple reinstalls, tests of different drivers, so on and so fourth, i have been unable to find a solution to my problems.

The symptoms of the game are:

- Black screen with white loading bar at bottom, before nothing
- After
  initial loading is complete the game does manage to play some sound

I believe a rather important clue to solving this problem is an error that pops up before starting the game. The error says:

```
Unsupported version of OpenGL! Detected OpenGL version: 3.0 MEsa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA. 
Required OpenGL version: 3.3. 
Please update your display driver"
```

I have tried to update my display driver using multiple different Mesa PPAs, but with no luck. I have also tried to launch the game with this launch argument:

```
"MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3COMPAT".
```

Also without any luck.

running "glxinfo | grep version" returns this information:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 13.1.0-devel - padoka PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

The system is running an AMD R9-290x (Gallium 0.4 on AMD HAWAII (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-45-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)) with an Intel I7-4770k, on an ASUS Z97-deluxe, running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 1):

Put this into the Launch Options for your game:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=430 %command%
```

Replace "4.3" with your version of OpenGL from the OpenGL core profile version string returned from `glxinfo | grep version` and replace "430" with your OpenGL version multiplied by 100

Comment: Actually, with 18.04.4 LTS, this is no longer necessary.