# Intel Whiskey Lake OpenGL 4?

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl, mesa

I have a Whiskey Lake processor.  How can I get a mesa version that supports OpenGL 4 on this arch?  I've followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), but I still get:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

How do I get OpenGL 4+ API on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa](https://launchpad.net/%7Epaulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa)

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```