# How can I get my display back? xmodmap: unable to open display ''

Tags: ppa, intel-graphics, xmodmap

Like so many others, I've been trying to upgrade my OpenGL from 3.0 to 3.2, which was probably a terrible idea to begin with but here we are. Now my Ubuntu partition will not open properly and I'm currently running on the 2nd partition of my laptop containing PureOS. I think the problem comes from having tried to install ppa's, but I hope the community can help me out because I'm really stuck and I need my Ubuntu!

First some hardware/system details:
Machine: Librem 13
OS type: 64-bit
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

After logging in, I stay on the command line and it says `xmodmap: unable to open display`. Indeed `echo $DISPLAY` returns nothing. Running `glxinfo` returns "Error: unable to open display".

Here is the output for `lshw` for the graphics card:

```
sudo lshw -c video
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 620
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:125 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:1c00(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Here's the output from `apt policy`. I tried to remove items not relevant here like those from "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu". Some of the ppa's were installed in an attempt to get to OpenGL 3.2 and should probably be removed:

```
apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-x-swat-updates,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Updates,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-x-swat-updates,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Updates,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-oibaf-graphics-drivers,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Updated Open Graphics Drivers - since 2011!,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-oibaf-graphics-drivers,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Updated Open Graphics Drivers - since 2011!,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=i386
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Partner archive,c=partner,b=amd64
     origin archive.canonical.com
```

And finally, `lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d30 (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.5 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Device 9d24 (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

- What's the problem causing xmodmap to fail?
- Should I remove the oibaf ppa's?
- Should I remove the ubuntu-x-swat ppa's?

Any help much appreciated!

(sorry if this has been discussed elsewhere in the forum, I searched on xmodmap and didn't find anything relevant)

**EDIT: I didn't follow one tutorial in particular, but here's a brief recap:**

GLX was returning a bad value so I did `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440:i386` inspired by this issue with Steam: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/fu1228/steam_no_longer_launching_after_recent_ubuntu/

That seemed to make GLX work better:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
```

(At some I also edited /etc/X11/xorg.conf as described at the bottom of this page: https://public.confluence.arizona.edu/display/UAHPC/Visualization)

Since I need OpenGL 3.2, I added the `ubuntu-x-swap` ppa because I thought I was missing some updates, following http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/install-mesa-19-0-8-ubuntu-18-04-19-04/

Also added the `oibaf` repository too see if that would upgrade OpenGL, based on this 6 year old thread: [How to update OpenGL Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Sorry about the mess.

Comment: Could you post, the link of the tutorial you followed, so we could see exactly what do you did

Comment: Please see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

**I think I found a way out of this mess by upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04!!**

Before attempting to upgrade, I removed weird non-proprietary PPA's, like oibaf, and rebooted (should probably have purged them instead of just removing).

I following the official guide here to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04:

https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today

At first, the upgrade would not happen because I "held broken packages". Looking into apt.log and main.log after the failed installation, I saw that xserver-xorg-video-* was causing the problems.

I then tried re-installing a couple of xserver drivers inspired by this thread: [16.04 - How To Purge Intel Default Drivers & Reinstall Intel Graphic Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers), more specifically:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

It seems that xserver-xorg-core got installed, BUT I get an error for xserver-xorg-video-intel saying "it cannot be downloaded". Then I tried a simple install instead:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Returning:

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git2005070730.e781d4"oibaf"b).
```

AHA! That's the "oibaf" PPA I removed earlier! Maybe that's what's messing things up? When I do

```
apt search xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

The driver from "oibaf" is the first that shows up as "xserver-xorg-video-intel/now" followed by 5 other drivers from bionic.

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg/bionic
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04/bionic
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04-dbg/bionic
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04-dbg/bionic-updates
```

From here I did a more specific set of install commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
```

Now the "oibaf" drivers dissappeared from the "apt search xserver-xorg-video-intel" output.

And "sudo do-release-update -d" worked! I have my desktop back.

Comment: that's great! i'm glad you rescued it!